# org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet has hardcoded session timeout

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

In one of our project we starting long time jobs on remote nodes. Those jobs sometimes can take few hours.
We've used old version some application which uses old version of Selenium WebDriver. And it works perfectly many years.
Now we've switched to new version of those application which uses new version of selenium WebDriver. And it stop to work.
I've reviewed all stack trace and see issue in class

org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet

When you execute any executor you hardcoded timeout for 10 minutes.

```
try {
  execution.get(10, MINUTES);
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
  resp.reset();
  JeeInterop.execute(new ExceptionHandler(e), req, resp);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  logger.log(Level.WARNING, "Unexpectedly interrupted: " + e.getMessage(), e);
  invalidateSession = true;

  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
  invalidateSession = true;
}
```

This is exactly what I'm seeing in our new application. I trying to set any timeout, but it closed session in 10 minutes.

Could you please explain why you do this?
Seems this is a bug.
Do you know any workaround to make it works?

Sincerely